# Do Lambda functions qualify for the SES free tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, documentation, amazon-ses, billing

I am currently unsure whether I can send outbound emails for my lambda functions through SES for free up to 62k messages. Documentation says that Ec2 and Beanstalk instances qualify but I read an old reddit thread from a few years ago saying that Lambdas execute on an EC2 instance and therefore do quality. What's the truth?

Official Documentation:

> As part of AWS Free Tier, AWS SES offers 62,000 Outbound Messages per month to any recipient when you call Amazon SES from an Amazon EC2 instance directly or through AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and 1,000 Inbound Messages per month.

Reddit Post:

> How AWS runs it is an implementation detail and is unrelated to billing. Most services in AWS run on EC2 internally.

> The billing details is a but unclear on what it means for EC2, but it means any application running inside AWS. For example: EC2 native, ECS, EKS, or as you're asking lambda. Basically it costs more if your application is not running in AWS.

Can anyone confirm if this is true? I cannot find any sources to totally confirm or deny.

I browsed through the official documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/) and found their explanation to be somewhat unclear, primarily due to what is stated [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/b7uek5/aws_ses_pricing_on_lambda_same_as_ec2_or_full/) in the first comment.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/753636

Comment: The normal cost for Amazon SES (after the free tier) is `$0.10/1000 emails`. Therefore, the free 62,000 messages are giving you $6.20 value each month. Is the need to avoid that $6.20 charge worth changing your entire architecture?